# Spark driver fails when running zstd compression on multiple threads in databricks single node cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, cluster-computing, azure-databricks, zstd

I'm using a single node databricks cluster with the following configuration:
[image]
[image]

I need to write partitions from different dataframes in zstd compressed .csv files and upload them to DBFS. What I would like to do is to run the compression process on multiple threads with different parts of the dataframe (the dataframe is filtered by some criteria). What I tried so far is this (Python):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class FileCreation:

    def __init__()
        #...
        # init the data frame and file path

    def create_files(self, df, country, partitions):
        df.coalesce(partitions).write.csv(os.path.join(self.storage_path, f"country={country}"), compression="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.ZStandardCodec", header=True, mode="overwrite")
 
    def process(self) -> None:
            countries: List[str] = self.get_country_codes(df) # returns a list like ["Germany", "Netherlands"...] depending on different countries existing in dataset
        self.run(countries)

    def run(self, countries):
            with ThreadPool(processes=int(32)) as pool:
                    return pool.map(self.process_country, countries)

    def process_country(self, country):
        df = self.filter() # performs a filter on the dataframe based on country
        partitions =  self.get_number_of_necessary_partitions(df) #returns the number of partitions based on a defined number of rows in a file
        self.create_files(country, partition)



file_creation = FileCreation(...)
file_creation.process()
```

The script works, some files are uploaded but at some point the Spark culster stoppes unexpectedly. I have to mention the data comes with 4 partitions by default but I need to reduce them based on calculated number of partitions.I need the job to run for aprox one hour. I had a look on the logs but nothing helpful. I read that zstd compression can have problems with multiple threads. Any ideea what I can do? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: To be clear, zstd isn't _intrinsically_ unsafe in threaded environments; it just needs to be used correctly. To quote the documentation: *In multi-threaded environments, use one different context per thread for parallel execution.*

Comment: Yes. After monitoring the memory and cpu usage on the cluster I found the issue. For each thread there is a copy of the dataframe created and the dataframe is quite big so the cluster fails because of the memory usage. I need to find a solution to share the df between threads (each needs to process a different part of it, reading operations should not affect the processing)